# How to reload the ionic view?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a sidemenu based app, in that after login I am displaying a number of tasks. If I click on the task it will redirect to the task details page, in that page I can update the tasks.

So after updating a task I need to go back to the previous task list page. I am using `$ionicHistory.goBack();` to go back.

My problem is after come back, I need to refresh the task list i.e. updated task should not be there in the task list. How can I refresh/reload the task list?

Comment: Steps to refresh Ionic view when go back 1. Configuration to disable cache in ionic and refresh view 2. Disable cache in view  . have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HExPUfuaRwU or this link  http://www.codeandyou.com/2017/08/how-to-refresh-view-in-ionic.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you bind your task to a `tasks` array, which will be used in the `task list` page, it should be automatically updated.

But the question is about not displaying, newly added tasks (still my previous suggestion should work) if not, performance reasons ionic views are cached, So when you come back to the previous view it doesn't go through the normal loading cycle. But you 2 options

1 - disable the `caching` by using `<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">` in your `ion-view`, but this is not a very elegant solution. [read more](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

2 - use `ionRefresher` (my preferred). [read more here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/)

Comment: @user3190207, great.. hope you'll accept my answer :D

Comment: HI i have one more question i need to sent my current latitude and longitude to web service in each 5 mint while app is in background state. can you please help?

Comment: @MunavvarFairoos, AFAIK, there is no one plugin/code to do that, however , you could use `geolocation` (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/) to get the current position and send it through `angular`. So that there could be plugins, or simply can use `$interval`  (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to periodically execute a method, HTH

Comment: i i am getting a warning like this "['Geolocation'] took '36.611084' ms. Plugin should use a background thread" how to use background thread in ionic?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582

according to @hpawe01 "If you are using the current ionicframework (ionic: v1.0.0-beta.14, angularjs: v1.3.6, angular-ui-router: v0.2.13), the problem with the not-reloading-controller could be caused by the new caching-system of ionic:
Note that because we are caching these views, we aren’t destroying scopes. Instead, scopes are being disconnected from the watch cycle. Because scopes are not being destroyed and recreated,controllers are not loading again on a subsequent viewing.
There are several ways to disable caching. To disable it only for a single state, just add cache: false to the state definition.
This fixed the problem for me (after hours of reading, trying, frustration).
For all others not using ionicframework and still facing this problem: good luck!"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks will let you know the result.thanls a lot

Comment: No problems!
Was stuck in some other problem i came across this bug, had to read over 18 months of comments to find this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also listen to ionic events such as `$ionicView.enter` on `$scope` and trigger the code that refreshes the list if you haven't bound your list as @sameera207 suggested.

EG:

```
// List.controller.js

angular.module('app')
    .controller('ListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    // See http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ for full events list
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        _someCodeThatFetchesTasks()
            .then(function(tasks) {
                $scope.tasks = tasks;
            });
    });

});
```

Bear in mind that it's not the most proper way (if proper at all) and if you do this you certainly have a design flaw. Instead you should share the same data array via a `factory` or a `service` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For your task you can also use [ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/).

It is well documented. And if you are using now Ionic 2 beta you can use some of the view lifecyle hooks like `onPageWillLeave()` or `onPageWillEnter()`. I just faced the same problem and defined a refresh() function, but the user had to click on a button to actually update the view. But then I found:

https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/

You just have to import the Page and NavController module and also define it in the constructor. The you can use for example onPageWillEnter(), which will always invoke when you go again to a view:

```
onPageWillEnter() {
    // Do whatever you want here the following code is just to show you an example. I needed it to refresh the sqlite database
    this.storage.query("SELECT * FROM archivedInserates").then((data) = > {
            this.archivedInserates =[];
    if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.res.rows.length; i++) {
            this.archivedInserates.push({userName:data.res.rows.item(i).userName, email:
            data.res.rows.item(i).email});
        }
    }
    },(error) =>{
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
    });
}
```

With ionic beta 8 the lifecylcle events changed their names. Check out the [official ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-beta-8-is-live/) for the full list of the lifecycle events.

Answer (score 0):

if you are building data driven app then make sure use `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`in your app.config so that each review can refresh for more details read this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/